# Is necessary to encode HTML in JSON to HEX?

Tags: javascript, php, json, character-encoding, xss

In my website, any html tag from a user input is escaped by `htmlspecialchars`, then I send html tags + escaped user content as a JSON variable using PHP `json_encode`, this escapes all “ as \”, only the ones that I put in the html because the user input is already escaped.

That works just fine, I had no problems, I don’t see how a XSS attack would be possible, and I tried.

But I see that Twitter and facebook encode to HEX all html tags, so if I would do the same I would add the options `JSON_HEX_TAG JSON_HEX_AMP JSON_HEX_APOS JSON_HEX_QUOT` to `json_encode()`.

So why are twitter and facebook doing this and why I should? I couldn’t create a security error.

Comment: `on a older browser` ... erm, Edge is **not** an onlder browser

Comment: @Jaromanda What I mean is it Works well in all browsers I tested IE9+ Edge Firefox Chrome Opera. I just say as a curiosity, that if you look at the JSON file, so if you enter the developer tools and you search on the Network tab, the browser does not color well the variables that have " escaped as \". It Works perfectly on Edge, so I only say as a hypothesis, that maybe the coloring engine is not updated and it Works like and old browser would read the JSON file, just guessing.

Comment: so, your question isn't about a problem with code, it's about developer tools console pretty print?

Comment: No, I think I will edit the question, the coloring thing is almost an off topic, I tried to explain that this is the only wrong thing I found, which is not a problem at all. I want to know the reason why Twitter and Facebook encode this tags, and If I should do it too.

Comment: My bad, actually it colours it well, I didn't set up the header content type properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy sounds fine from a XSS standpoint. The hex encoding is perhaps to support other languages/character sets?

Comment: This (multibyte Unicode) is done by default since PHP 5.4.0, so I'm doing it too. They are encoding HTML tags, so: < > & " ' as HEX, the default `json_encode` only escapes " as \" it does not encode HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you'd need to escape brackets and quotes because they can escape out of the surrounding html context. `json_encode` by itself is only useful if you're outputting to a '.js' file without any html around it.

Both methods can prevent XSS, but the difference is that they produce different output. `htmlspecialchars` converts '<' to '&lt;' (an html entity), and hex encoding converts '<' to '\u003C' (a JavaScript string literal escape sequence). If you're sending data to a JavaScript variable, then you want the JavaScript one to ensure data integrity.

Say you want to send the message "One month's time" to JavaScript.

With hex encoding, you write:

```
<script>
    var input = <?php
        $input = "One month's time";

        $input = json_encode($input, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT);

        echo $input;
    ?>;
    console.log(input);
</script>
```

and it will output "One month's time", as you want.

With `htmlspecialchars`, you write:

```
<script>
    var input = <?php
        $input = "One month's time";

        $input = htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
        $input = json_encode($input);

        echo $input;
    ?>;
    console.log(input);
</script>
```

and it will output "One month&#039;s time", which has corrupted the data. This is because it's HTML encoded but wasn't inserted directly into a HTML context.

You should use HTML encoding if you're setting an innerHTML property, or similar, though to prevent DOM-based XSS, but this can be done with JavaScript rather than PHP.